# Left category menu - change the rendering of just one menu item

Tags: php, opencart

The code

```
<div class="box">
  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
  <li>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
```

I need to change the way how a concrete menu item is rendered, let's say for a category with ID 73. How can I do this in the above template?

Comment: Is this category a parent one or a child category?